# Two apps same SignalR server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, azure-signalr

I have a web API project which is configured to connect to Azure SignalR and clients can connect to it through its hub.

**Web Api:**

```
    [Authorize]
    public class ClientHub : Hub
    {
        private string GroupName
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{Context?.User?.GetClaim(ClaimTypes.Role) ?? null}_{ Context?.User?.GetClaim(ClaimType.hdid) ?? null}";
            }
        }

        public ClientHub()
        {

        }
        public async override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnConnectedAsync");

            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context?.ConnectionId, GroupName);

            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnDisconnectedAsync");

            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
```

```
   public class SignalRService : IDataPushService
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<ClientHub> _hubContext;

        public SignalRService(IHubContext<ClientHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public Task Receive(string data)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public async Task Send(PushServiceDataPackage dataPackage)
        {
            await _hubContext.Clients.Group(dataPackage.GroupName)
                .SendAsync(dataPackage.EventType.ToString(), dataPackage.Data);
        }
    }
```

> ConfigureServices method

```
            // Add SignalR service
        bool.TryParse(configuration["SignalRSettings:EnableDetailedErrors"], out bool enableDetailedErrors);
        services.AddSignalR(config => config.EnableDetailedErrors = enableDetailedErrors).AddAzureSignalR(configuration["SignalRSettings:ConnectionString"]);
```

> Configure method:

```
 endpoints.MapHub<ClientHub>(configuration["SignalRSettings:HubPath"]);
```

**Console App:**
I also have a console app that is meant to use the same SignalR server to send data to connected clients.

```
bool.TryParse(hostContext.Configuration["SignalRSettings:EnableDetailedErrors"], out bool enableDetailedErrors);
services.AddSignalR(config => config.EnableDetailedErrors = enableDetailedErrors).AddAzureSignalR(hostContext.Configuration["SignalRSettings:ConnectionString"]);
```

```
  public class SignalRService : IDataPushService
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<Hub> _hubContext;

        public SignalRService(IHubContext<Hub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public Task Receive(string data)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public async Task Send(PushServiceDataPackage dataPackage)
        {
            await _hubContext.Clients.Group(dataPackage.GroupName)
                .SendAsync(dataPackage.EventType.ToString(), dataPackage.Data);
        }
    }
```

**How can I access the clients connected to the server in the console app?**

> Please note that there are two apps and one Azure SignalR server?

Comment: Azure signalr service will dispatch the incoming message and outgoing  messages to  correct server and clients. And we can see the sample for asp.net core signalr, the connections between clients and server is based on the url `var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();
` but you said that you have 2 applications, so I'm afraid that your requirement can't be realized.